# PHP if based on current system date

Tags: php

Trying to setup a page that auto updates based on the users date/time.

Need to run a promotion for 2 weeks and each day it needs to change the displayed image.
Was reading through http://www.thetricky.net/php/Compare%20dates%20with%20PHP to get a better handle on php's time and date functions.Somewhat tricky to test, but I basically got stuck on:

```
<?php
$dateA = '2012-07-16'; 
$dateB = '2012-07-17'; 

if(date() = $dateA){ 
  echo 'todays message';
}
else if(date() = $dateB){
    echo 'tomorrows message';
}
?>
```

I know the above function is wrong as its setup, but I think it explains what I am aiming for.
Time is irrelevant, it needs to switch over at midnight so the date will change anyway.

Comment: `if` requires `==` or `===`. You're using a single `=`. Does it compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to need this:

```
<?php
$dateA = '2012-07-16'; 
$dateB = '2012-07-17'; 

if(date('Y-m-d') == $dateA){ 
    echo 'todays message';
} else if(date('Y-m-d') == $dateB){
    echo 'tomorrows message';
}
?>
```

Comment: +1, Although you probably would need to call: `date('Y-m-d')` instead

Comment: $today = date('Y-m-d'); if( $today === $dateA ){} else after 10 days you got PHP to compute date() 10 times ;) EDIT, DOH, bigkm said the same, sorry ...

Comment: Yep, did it to make it look like the original code.. bigkm's answer is a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

you want

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d')
if($today == $dateA) {
    echo 'todays message';
} else if($today == $dateB) {
    echo 'tomorrows message';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go a step back and handle it via file names. Something like:

```
<img src=/path/to/your/images/img-YYYY-MM-DD.jpg alt="alternative text">
```

So your script would look something like this:

```
<img src=/path/to/your/images/img-<?php echo date('Y-m-d', time()); ?>.jpg alt="alternative text">
```

Comment: It's a way to display an image on a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do date calculations, I'd recommend using PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$promotion_starts = "2012-07-16"; // When the promotion starts

// An array of images that you want to display, 0 = the first day, 1 = the second day
$images = array( 
    0 => 'img_1_start.png',
    1 => 'the_second_image.jpg'
);

$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

// The current date, without any time values
$now = new DateTime( "now", $tz);
$now->setTime( 0, 0, 0);

$start    = new DateTime( $promotion_starts, $tz);
$interval = new DateInterval( 'P1D'); // 1 day interval
$period   = new DatePeriod( $start, $interval, 14); // 2 weeks

foreach( $period as $i => $date) {
    if( $date->diff( $now)->format("%d") == 0) {
        echo "Today I should display a message for " . $date->format('Y-m-d') . " ($i)\n";
        echo "I would have displayed: " . $images[$i] . "\n"; // echo <img> tag
        break;
    }
}
```

Given that the promotion starts on `07-16`, [this displays](http://viper-7.com/I8sLDJ) the following, since it is now the second day of the promotion:

```
Today I should display a message for 2012-07-17 (1)
I would have displayed: the_second_image.jpg
```